# Efficient & Productive Way of Uploading Products

Tags: product, database, import

I am looking for some advice and tips on how to go about uploading hundred of thousands of products onto a Magento store in my lifetime.

Today, I discovered Magmi which is a godsend for uploading CSV files at a fast speed however it still requires you to manually enter in the data. I have timed myself for each product I add, and on average I take about 5 minutes. I have quite a few extra product attributes :) So if you do the math, 5 minutes times lets say 10,000 products or more, well you get the idea.

I'm thinking of hiring a freelancer that will write a script to scrape the appropriate data from my suppliers and export it as a CSV file however since I have quiet a few suppliers this might be expensive. Also some of my suppliers provide spreadsheets of their products, while some don't.

Is there an efficient and productive way of accomplishing a task like this?

Comment: What is expensive? someone entering all products(hours of work) or creating solutions per supplier which you can reuse over and over again

Comment: You must have some sort of source of data you're referencing while creating the CSV for Magmi. What is it/format?

Comment: @JeroenBoersma It's going to be expensive to create a solution per supplier.

Comment: @musicliftsme what do you mean? As of right now, I simply manually enter all information for CSV.

Comment: @thes4s, you get digital data (text files, spreadsheets, etc.) from you suppliers and use what you get from them to create a CSV file for Magmi?

Comment: @musicliftsme Well a few of my suppliers provide a CSV file with the product names, description etc. However, the format they have is not the same so I manually edit each to fit my CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, getting inconsistent data makes it impossible to upload these products to Magento, whether you use Magmi or a custom solution, automatically.

What you would need to do is standardize the data from your supplier (also sometimes impossible).. That way, a program/extension can read that data and act accordingly as you instructed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but not one a small business uses. You want enterprise tools which take the datasets, reformat them based on business rules without programming, cleans them, and loads them to Magento. We launch our sites via an incubator who has this technology so makes our life simple, it processes up to 15m products per day. The problem with Magmi is it's good for initial loads but not maintenance, you need to reindex and Magento just isn't designed well to do that. The simple answer is you need to hire the manual resource to perform data entry, create the Magmi datasets,or find high-grade tools to perform the data cleaning which are generally only available to large companies. Excel is the quickest way of creating the datasets which you can feed in to Magmi manually, but it's not time friendly as you have found out.

Comment: No problem, technically the statement about inconsistent data is not correct, the problem is small business doesn't have access to the technology in large companies. The people we work with who have these tools are always willing to work with rational requests (you would be surprised the percentage which are irrational) and can handle inconsistent datasets. Hey, they're even providing a business orientated full international eCommerce architecture with hosting, marketing & consulting gratis as a kickstarter.